# Group By id and Sum get sum to set new using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays

Would it be possible to sort and group by (say, "id") and update the values of the Elements by adding all unique values of the Key (eg: payout) using Lodash?
For example, could this array below:

```
[
  {
     id: 1,
     payout: 15,
     numOfPeople: 4
  },
  {
     id: 1,
     payout: 12,
     numOfPeople: 3
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     payout: 6,
     numOfPeople: 5
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     payout: 10,
     numOfPeople: 1
  }
]
```

... be transformed into the one like below using LODASH:

```
  // Notice the Sum of all payout reflects the total sum of all
  // payout with id=1 or id=2 (for a specific id Group)

[
  {
     id: 1,
     payout: 27,
     numOfPeople: 4
  },
  {
     id: 1,
     payout: 27,
     numOfPeople: 3
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     payout: 16,
     numOfPeople: 5
  },
  {
     id: 2,
     payout: 16,
     numOfPeople: 1
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: `thearray.map((f) => { const n = Object.assign({}, f); n.payout = a.filter((v) => v.id === f.id).reduce((a, v) => a + v.payout, 0); return n; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `filter`, `map` and `reduce` to do this.

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    payout: 15,
    numOfPeople: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    payout: 12,
    numOfPeople: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    payout: 6,
    numOfPeople: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    payout: 10,
    numOfPeople: 1,
  },
];

const idPayoutMap = {};

let result = arr.map(x => {
  if (idPayoutMap['' + x.id] !== undefined) {
    x.payout = idPayoutMap['' + x.id];
  } else {
    x.payout = arr
      .filter(y => y.id === x.id)
      .reduce((totalPayout, y) => y.payout + totalPayout, 0);
    idPayoutMap['' + x.id] = x.payout;
  }

  return x;
});


console.log(result);
```

Here is a working sample: [Sample](https://repl.it/repls/ComposedBabyishAvians)

Comment: if before sum can i check payout >0 that biger than zero